# How can i get Phone Number using Graph API

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api

I'm not able to Get any user Phone number from `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`

I'm getting phone number `null` - even though my profile is linked to phone number

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
  "displayName": "random",
  "surname": "name",
  "givenName": "name",
  "id": "xbxbxbbx",
  "userPrincipalName": "shdfn@outlook.com",
  "businessPhones": [],
  "jobTitle": null,
  "mail": null,
  "mobilePhone": null,
  "officeLocation": null,
  "preferredLanguage": null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Phone Numbers are not available for personal Microsft Accounts (MSA). They're only returned for Work/School accounts (AAD).